# How to use WURFL in servlet as I m missing WURFLEngine

Tags: java, classpath, wurfl

Thanks in advance. I am using first time this WURFL API

I am using `wurfl-1.3.1.1.jar` and `wurfl-1.5.1.1-javadoc.jar` in my demo application for detecting mobile browser capability.

But here in this jar I am not finding `net.sourceforge.wurfl.core.WURFLEngine` class so its failing at the compile time.

Please guide me how to proceed on this.

Note: If some one can provide me steps in detail "how to use wurfl" then it will be great for me.

Comment: Get the version(wurfl-1.5.1.1.jar) which contains 'net.sourceforge.wurfl.core.WURFLEngine'.

Comment: Thank you so much. But can you please share me the link from where i can get the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Hi WURFL Creator and ScientiaMobile CTO here.

Version 1.5 of the WURFL API for Java has introduced several semplifications of the class structure.

APIs can be downloaded here:

https://www.scientiamobile.com/downloads

as far as Java is concerned, you may want to refer to the following links:

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/njava_index.php

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/javamigration_to_1dot5.php

If you post the specific code on the ScientiaMobile forum, that's the space that the WURFL support team monitors regularly and we should be able to assist more specifically. We also keep an eye on StackOverflow, but this is not our official support channel.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right I will fallow your suggestion in your official site. But When I tried with new 1.5 jar it is compiling properly but it is giving StackOverflowError when I am executing the same war on my local JBOSS server. Can you please let me know if I will increase the JVM space like this JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m" then what is the expected space I should keep for the JVM .

Comment: ERROR:
23:32:01,526 INFO  [MatcherManager] model devices: 23778
23:32:02,618 INFO  [MatcherManager] model devices filtered: 23778
23:32:02,878 INFO  [DefaultWURFLService] DefaultWURFLService created
23:32:02,878 INFO  [GeneralWURFLEngine] Device Provider is fed: net.sourceforge.wurfl.core.DefaultDeviceProvider
23:32:03,038 ERROR [[controller]] Servlet.service() for servlet controller threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at

Comment: I asked the engineering team and it is hard to understand what you are doing wrong based on the info you posted here. Can you post a complete StackTrace? code snippet? 
We suggest that you post on our forum. We also have the ability to contact people offline and figure out a solution faster through faster interaction.